# glVertexAttributePointer scope?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, vbo, vertexdata

I'm currently programming an OpenGL ES 2.0 application on both iOS and Android platforms.

In this application I render multiple meshes that all use VBOs. In the process of optimizing the rendering, I realized that the meshes I render share two vertex formats. So I wanted to do the following:

First, setup all vertex attribute pointer offsets, and then simply bind each VBO that uses this vertex format and render it without calling the `glVertexAttribPointer` function again.

But it gives me strange results.

My question is: Do we have to do the calls `glVertexAttribPointer` each time we bind a new VBO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, like every OpenGL state, the state set with `glVertexAttribPointer` keeps unchanged until someone else calls `glVertexAttribPointer` again (for the same attribute index). But the important thing here is, that the internal state changed with `glVertexAttribPointer` doesn't just store the buffer offset to be used for rendering, offsetting into the VBO bound when calling `glDraw...`. It also **stores the actual buffer object** bound when calling `glVertexAttribPointer`.

So yes, whenever you want your vertex data sourced from another VBO, you need to bind this VBO and do the appropriate `glVertexAttribPointer` calls while this VBO is bound. While this may seem cumbersome in your case, this is in fact a good thing. This way you don't need to worry about the currently bound buffer when rendering something, but only about the things set up with `glVertexAttribPointer`. And even more important it let's bind a different VBO before rendering, thus you can source different vertex attributes from different VBOs in a single render call (how else would you do that?).

**EDIT:** You can however use [Vertex Array Objects](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_vertex_array_object.txt) to ease the process of setting up your vertex data. They encapsulate all the state neccessary for rendering from a bunch of arrays (and thus all the things changed by `glVertexAttribPointer`, `gl(En/Dis)ableVertexAttribArray` and the buffer bound to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, but like said, **not** the buffer bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`). You still have to properly bind the buffer before calling `glVertexAttribPointer` of course. But using a VAO you only need this code in some set up routine and all you need to do for rendering is calling `glBindVertexArray`. Though I don't know if your particular ES device supports them.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I suspected. I'll try to use VAOs, One question is, how efficient is it compared to the classic glBindBuffer-glVertexAttribPointer approach ?

Comment: @F.L. It shouldn't have any significant performance impact. In the end a VAO might be slightly more efficient, since you only have to make a single driver call compared to a bunch each time when rendering. But in the end the driver itself will just do the `glVertexAttribPointer` calls internally somehow. But maybe it might even circumvent some sanity checks it has to do when calling `glVertexAttribPointer`, which needn't be done when binding the VAO, of course. But really, in practice VAOs are more about usability than actual perfomance, I think (though it shouldn't be slower than no VAO).

Comment: What about `glEnableVertexAttribArray` does that need to be reset when swapping VBOs?

Comment: @nmr No, why should it? It's entirely independent of any buffers, afterall it's just a simple yes/no enable-flag for each individual attribute index, no matter what buffers their actual data will be sourced from, if any at all.

Comment: Beats me, AFAICT GL state is associated almost at random :) Just trying to figure out what's associated with what.

Comment: @nmr Well, it isn't too unreasonable if you know the principles. But I agree, there are some places that could use reworking. In fact the whole atttribute stuff is to a large degree indebted to already deprecated things like client arrays (`glVertexAttribPointer`? WTH is a pointer, it's a friggin buffer), but that also got reworked recently (some 4.x so to say) with a new way of associating buffers to attributes and separating the actual buffer from the format.

Answer (score 1):

Some cool resource I found on drawing with VAO / VBO

http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tutorial%2005.html#d0e4720

It shows how you can drive several objects, with several VAOs and a single VBO for example (each VAO holding pointers with different offsets to the same VBO)

Definitively worth a look, not mentioning the part where you learn that

- `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER...`doesn't bind any data, it's just a
  global pointer for the following `glVertexAttribPointer` calls which do the actual data binding

BUT

- `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER...`DOES bind/save the element array into the current VAO